# Why am I getting an error when I try to get a string from my table in a Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, indexoutofboundsexception

I am fairly new to programming; my program is a television show scheduler and I'm trying to grab a variable from the timetable(schedule) I have created. The error is happening on the 6th line.

```
if (dayOfTheWeek=="Saturday"){
    int saturdayCOUNT=0;
    String[] SATURDAYSHOW = new String[9];
    SATURDAYSHOW=null;

    while (saturdayCOUNT<10){
         SATURDAYSHOW[saturdayCOUNT] = (String) timetable.getValueAt(saturdayCOUNT, 5);
         saturdayCOUNT = saturdayCOUNT+1;
    }

    test1.setText(SATURDAYSHOW[0]);
    test2.setText(SATURDAYSHOW[1]);
    test3.setText(SATURDAYSHOW[2]);
    test4.setText(SATURDAYSHOW[3]);
    test5.setText(SATURDAYSHOW[4]);
    test6.setText(SATURDAYSHOW[5]);
    test7.setText(SATURDAYSHOW[6]);
    test8.setText(SATURDAYSHOW[7]);
    test9.setText(SATURDAYSHOW[8]);
    test10.setText(SATURDAYSHOW[9]);
    showPopup();
}
```

The error is

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
>       at my.UI.SchedulerUI.jButton1ActionPerformed(SchedulerUI.java:1412)

Comment: Don't know if it's the error you're getting, but setting an array to `null` and then trying to assign things into it is NEVER going to work.

Comment: You may also wish to check out how to compare `String` values.  It's seldom a good plan to use `==` for this.

Comment: Also, don't use "==" for comparison. You should be using the `equals(...)` method. Variable names should not be upper cased.

Comment: I've removed the line that set the array to null, and I've changed the == to .equals , neither of these things were causing the error.

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: i just added the error to the description of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `String[] SATURDAYSHOW = new String[9];` to `String[] SATURDAYSHOW = new String[10];`

Your array index is out of bounds, meaning that you are attempting to add more values than the array can physically hold.

Comment: haha, such a simple answer for something i thought was complicated. Thanks!